# Position of minipage

Tags: positioning, minipage

I want to have the footnote of a table to right side of it so I used the minipage environment. For some reason, the footnote takes half of the space of the table instead of being entirely to the right of it. How do I avoid this overlap?

```
\begin{table}[ht!]
\caption{Descriptive Statistics}
\begin{minipage}{0.2\textwidth} 
\resizebox{8cm}{!} {\begin{tabular}{cccc}     
\hline \hline 
 Variables   & Mean & Std. dev. & Range \\  
\hline \\
\textit{variable1} & 0.50 & 0.42 & 0-1 \vspace{1mm} \\ 
\textit{variable2} & 0.11 & 0.76 & 0-1 \vspace{1mm} \\ 
\textit{variable3} & 34.95 &  9.99  & 25-65 \vspace{1mm} \\ 
\textit{variable4} & 34.95 &  9.99  & 25-65 \vspace{4mm} \\  
\hline Observations & & & 256 
\end{tabular}} 
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
\footnotesize \textit{Notes}: Description of variable1, variable2, variable3, variable4
\end{minipage}
\end{table}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: A warm welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: try with `\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}` and you can replace `\begin{minipage}{0.2\textwidth}` with `\begin{minipage}{0.48\textwidth}`

Comment: @erik, thank you for your remark and apologies for making it inconvenient. Since it's my first time using TEX.SE, I forgot about that. Will do next time.

Comment: @SevT. No worries. It was just a reminder (to readers and potential future posters as well).

Answer (score 1):

The key point is to use: `\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}`. The best is to define new length and set it to `8cm`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}  

\begin{table}[ht!]
\caption{Descriptive Statistics}
\begin{minipage}{0.49\linewidth} 
\resizebox{\textwidth}{!} {\begin{tabular}{cccc}     
\hline \hline 
 Variables   & Mean & Std. dev. & Range \\  
\hline \\
\textit{variable1} & 0.50 & 0.42 & 0-1 \vspace{1mm} \\ 
\textit{variable2} & 0.11 & 0.76 & 0-1 \vspace{1mm} \\ 
\textit{variable3} & 34.95 &  9.99  & 25-65 \vspace{1mm} \\ 
\textit{variable4} & 34.95 &  9.99  & 25-65 \vspace{4mm} \\  
\hline Observations & & & 256 
\end{tabular}} 
\end{minipage}%   %<----- no space
\begin{minipage}{0.5\linewidth}
\footnotesize \textit{Notes}: Description of variable1, variable2, variable3, variable4
\end{minipage}
\end{table}

\newlength{\mytabularwidth}
\setlength{\mytabularwidth}{8cm}
\begin{table}[ht!]
\caption{Descriptive Statistics}
\begin{minipage}{\mytabularwidth} 
\resizebox{\textwidth}{!} {\begin{tabular}{cccc}     
\hline \hline 
 Variables   & Mean & Std. dev. & Range \\  
\hline \\
\textit{variable1} & 0.50 & 0.42 & 0-1 \vspace{1mm} \\ 
\textit{variable2} & 0.11 & 0.76 & 0-1 \vspace{1mm} \\ 
\textit{variable3} & 34.95 &  9.99  & 25-65 \vspace{1mm} \\ 
\textit{variable4} & 34.95 &  9.99  & 25-65 \vspace{4mm} \\  
\hline Observations & & & 256 
\end{tabular}} 
\end{minipage}%   %<----- no space
\begin{minipage}{\dimexpr\linewidth-\mytabularwidth\relax}
\footnotesize \textit{Notes}: Description of variable1, variable2, variable3, variable4
\end{minipage}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much touhami for your help! That solved my problem.